# Django - Single post view, Prev / Next links

Tags: python, django

I have built a blog app as part of a django tutorial and I can paginate the blog list view using the code from djangoproject - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/pagination/#using-paginator-in-a-view. I'm just having problems retrieving Prev / Next url slug links based on the current page post view.

model.py

```
class Film(Timestamp):
title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
image = ImageField(upload_to='thumb')
video = EmbedVideoField(blank=True)
director = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True)
cinematographer = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True)
producer = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True)
publish = models.BooleanField(default=False)
date_published = models.DateTimeField()

# override the admin name
class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = "Film Projects"

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.title

# helper method
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return "/film/%s/" % self.slug

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Film, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

views.py

```
# film single
def film_detail(request, slug):

film = Film.objects.get(slug=slug)

def get_next(self):
    next_post = Film.get_next_by_date_published()
    if next:
        return next.first()
    return False

def get_next(self):
    prev_post = Film.get_previous_by_date_published()
    if prev:
       return prev.first()
    return False

return render(request, 'film/film_detail.html', {
    'film': film,
})
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^film/$', views.film_list, name='film_list'),
url(r'^films/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.film_detail, name='film_detail'),
```

film_detail.html

```
<a href="{{ film.get_next_by_date_published }}">Next</a><br>
<a href="{{ film.get_previous_by_date_published }}">Previous</a>
```

The above links return next and previous post titles, not the slug and include the current post slug as well, for example - http://127.0.0.1:8000/films/sea-chair/Can Chair.

For such a simple thing (although I am new to django and python), I have spent days researching with no luck, I hope someone can help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `{{ film.get_next_by_date_published }}` returns a `film` object. To turn it into a url, you need to access `film.get_next_by_date_published.slug`.

You could hardcode the url in the template

```
<a href="/films/{{ film.get_next_by_date_published }}">Next</a>
```

However it's nicer to use the [`{% url %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#url) tag.

```
<a href="{% url 'film_detail' film.get_previous_by_date_published.slug %}">Next</a>
```

The next problem with this is that `get_next_by_date_published` and `get_previous_by_date_published` can raise a `DoesNotExist` exception if you are already at the last or first film respectively.

I would suggest fetching the next and previous films in the view, rather than trying to do it in the template. Note that I've used the `get_object_or_404` shortcut, to handle the case where a film with that slug does not exist.

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def film_detail(request, slug):

    film = get_object_or_404(Film, slug=slug)
    try:
        next_film = film.get_next_by_date_published()
    except Film.DoesNotExist:
        next_film = None

    try:
        previous_film = film.get_previous_by_date_published()
    except Film.DoesNotExist:
        previous_film = None

    return render(request, 'film/film_detail.html', {
        'film': film,
        'next_film': next_film,
        'previous_film': previous_film
    })
```

Then in your template, check that `next_film` exists before showing the link:

```
{% if next_film %}
<a href="{% url 'film_detail' next_film.slug %}">Next</a>
{% else %}
This is the last film!
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Hi Alasdair, that solution worked absolutely perfect, I can't thank you enough!!! After days of looking for a solution, I finally got the courage to ask and the first reply nailed it. Thanks again mate :)